# A "tap" created in Spring Cloud Stream will be saved as a "named destination"

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to understand concepts in Spring Cloud Stream. The 2 concepts "tap" and "named destination" are quite confusing to me.

I was trying to create a stream that has a tap called "some-source":

[image]

However, after I saved the stream, it became a "named destination":

[image]

My questions are:

1. What's the difference between a "tap" and a "named destination"?
2. Why would a "tap" become a "named destination" after saving the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `named` destination is a destination at the messaging system. For instance, an `exchange` at RabbitMQ or a `topic` at Apache Kafka.

Spring Cloud Stream takes care of creating these `named` destinations(say RabbitMQ exchange, Apache Kafka topic) when you have your inbound/outbound bindings set to specific destination names.

In SCDF, when you create a stream, SCDF configures these destination names with a specific syntax (.<App/Label Name of the producer app>).

For instance, let's say I create a stream like this:

S1=time | t1: transform | log

When the stream `S1` is deployed, you will see the destinations (if you use RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka then they will exchange or topic respectively) created with the following names:

S1.time
S1.t1

Because `time` and `transform` being the producers.

To answer your questions:

> What's the difference between a "tap" and a "named destination"?

In SCDF, a `tap` is essentially a `named` destination created on a producer app's outbound endpoint. Hence, when you add a tap on the stream S1's `time` output then you will end up using the `named` destination `S1.time`.

You can create a `tap` either at the time of your main stream creation (here S1) or you can create a new `tap` stream later on by referring to the named destinations of the stream (here S1.time, S1.t1)

> Why would a "tap" become a "named destination" after saving the stream?

Spring Cloud Stream has a consumer group model (inspired from Apache Kafka) implemented across all the binders it has support for. What this means is that,  every time a new consumer is bound to a `destination` at the messaging system (say an `exchange` at RabbitMQ or a `topic` at Apache Kafka), a new consumer group is created for that destination. A `tap` is nothing but creating a new stream which forms a new consumer group on a specific `named` destination.

There is one more case to add.

Let's say you want to create a stream that is not from an outbound endpoint of an existing stream but want to point to a specific `named` destination which has data from some other system. In those cases, you would use the `named` destination to create a stream. Because of the Spring Cloud Stream's consumer group model, you will create a new consumer group on this `named` destination as well.

For instance, let's say I have a RabbitMQ exchange or a Kafka topic named `user_data` which already receive data from other source that is not part of SCDF stream, then you will create a new stream like this:

```
:user_data > transform | jdbc
```

The prefix `:` is used to refer a named destination in SCDF.

Comment: I see. So, is it safe to say "tap" is a special kind of "named destination"?

Comment: Yes, It is in fact a named destination.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanation. I think I got it.